# How to provide timezone for dialogflow with actions-for-google/google assistant integration?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Dialogflow has the notion of a standard timezone per project, used eg to provide the real date for a utterance like "today" in system entities. However as users might not all be in the same timezone, I need to set the timezone per user/per conversation (users might travel across timezones). A timezone parameter is available in the dialogflow api when calling dialogflow from outside. However with the dialogflow actions-for-google/google assistant integration this api is only internally called.

Does anybody have a solution how to provide the timezone per conversation to dialogflow? Or are there any source code examples for a manual integration between actions-for-google and dialogflow (there is none at https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-nodejs-client/tree/master/samples ...)?

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no direct way to get the current timezone from actions-on-google.

The best you can do is [get permission to request the current location](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers#user_information) from the user, and then use something like the [Google Maps Timezone API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start) to get the timezone offset for that location.

Comment: Unfortunatly you misunderstand my problem. My problem is NOT how to figure the timezone out (you mentioned one of the possibilities, I have also access to a per-user default timezone), but how to feed the timezone into dialogflow so it is eg used when parsing system entities as described!